# Asus DSL-N12E router frequently drops Wi-Fi connections

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

I have a [Asus DSL-N12E](http://www.asus.com/Networking/DSLN12E/) router (DSL uplink + router + Wi-Fi AP) at house, and on average 5-10 devices which connects to it with Wi-Fi. Frequently different devices reports they lost Wi-Fi connection. Sometimes they reconnect seamlessly, sometimes one have to click “connect.” Always there’s no problem with reconnecting except sometimes you have to do it manually.

Yesterday I had 3 laptops on my desk (one with Linux/Debian, one with Windows 7 and one with Windows 8.1) and I noticed they all disconnect at the same moment. The router has some system log, but nothing there and I didn’t find an option to enable some extra logging; maybe I missed something?

I can’t think of any interference from the environment since I have no microwave and I live in the country with only 2 houses in the neighbourhood. I can’t see any Wi-Fi devices announcing, except 4 other wireless devices—link to the family house, and AP there—which are on different channels. Asus in on channel 11, the others on channel 8 and 3.

Any idea how to diagnose it, or what to change to fix the problem?

Comment: ...and signal level is about -50dBm, at least here on my desk where I tested yesterday

Comment: How often does this occur? Is it predictable (like every 30min)?

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Wireless Power Settings
If switching the router channel didn't work, you can try these other tips to help prevent your wireless connection from dropping.

First, see if your computer is managing your wireless card's power. It may be instructed to shut off your wireless connectivity after a certain amount of idle time goes by. If you have system specific utilities, such as Dell's Quickset, make sure that the wireless power management isn't set to shut off the card if your computer is idle for a certain period of time.  Second you'll want to check the settings on your wireless card via your device manager. In Windows XP:

Right-click on "My Computer" and select "Properties"
Select "Hardware" and click on "Device Manager"
Find your wireless card under "Network adapters" and double-click it.
Verify that there aren't any auto power management settings enabled that might be shutting your card down prematurely.
Power Cycle Your Hardware

Another thing to try is to simply shut down all your hardware - ie. your PC, your modem, your router, your laptop, etc. - anything on the network. Then power them back on in the following order: modem -> router -> PC (wired) -> laptop (wireless) and see if that fixes the issue. If not, proceed to more potential solutions below.

Update Your Router Firmware And Wireless Card Drivers
If all of the above hasn't prevented your wireless connection from dropping, you'll want to update the firmware of your wireless router, and you'll want to update your wireless card drivers.  This should solve the problem most of the time. With any firmware or driver update, please make sure you are retrieving the update directly from the manufacturer's website.